# Open Source Service risky?

Tags: open-source, service

Is it risky to have dependency on a open source service?

Unlike a open source dll or componenent the service obviously needs to be constantly running, therefore is it a business risk to rely on it? What happens if the open source service disappears for whatever reason?

The service under question would not be used for a business critical application but if successfull it will obviously gain in importance?

Many Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by an open-source service? In general, software is open-source. A service may be running open-source software, but there's no real way that a service as a whole can be considered "open-source", at least that I can think of.

Comment: The question reads like you've just equated the words "free" and "open source" - you might get a more effective answer if you can describe the service you are relying on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's really "Open Source" (as opposed to merely free), you can download the source and run it yourself it the original provider goes away.  Of course, you'd want to download the source ahead of time, because if the service provider goes away, there's not guarantee that there will be a site to download it from.  Also, you'd probably want to keep backups of the data for yourself if you can.

But if you're misusing the term "open source" to mean a free service like the Google Maps API, then yeah, if it goes away, you're boned.  But if Google Maps goes away, so is half the net.

Comment: The ladies don't call me "quickdraw" for nothing.

Comment: May be worth downloading the source in advance, as it may (possibly, though not necessarily likely) be hard to get after the demise.

Comment: The ladies don't call me at all.

Answer (score 4):

What exactly is an "open source service"?

- Any old website that offers an API? Yup, depending on it is a risk - they could go under or start charging a fee
- Or a site that publishes the software it's running under an open source license? Just download a copy and if the site goes away, you always have the option to run it yourself

Comment: The data is important, too.  To be a truly 'open source service' they need to provide access to any database required to run the code.  Otherwise you could still be in trouble.

Answer (score 3):

The better question is this:

**What happens if your paid enterprise you rely on goes under, and you're left without any code whatsoever, and no support?**

With that in retrospect, Open-source guarantees a future. All you have to do is find somebody to hack it. Proprietary on the other hand, legal hilarity ensues.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the same as a closed source service.

Both, usually, have the same chances of being closed, with the usual surprises of course, as also Google and Microsoft close services without any previous notice.

Same as Paul says, you can run that service if it gets very important, if it closes, or you need big things of it.

But most important thing, appart from being open or closed source, is the access to your data... in case the service closes or you need to move away... will you have access to all your raw data for moving?

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes. But if it is not a mission critical application, it might be okay.

I personally would try to avoid it just because of its vague future. But you never really know whether a commercial service will live through next year.

Just don't bind tightly to this service and not design strictly for it. Design so as to facilitate switch to another similar service in the future or even to a very different approach.

Design for the family of similar services. And always think of an escape plan in case this service goes away or even all services of the class.

I've also had similar considerations about this service: http://www.webservicex.net

Seems to be freely accessible but who really runs it and who can guarantee it will be there tomorrow?

As for tomorrow, even Google Mail happens to be down at some days. What do you want then of a free open-source service? :)